# NMAKE causing a "error U1052: file not found" on a file that does exist

Tags: nmake

I'm trying to follow the instructions for creating the "Zint Library DLL" on Visual Studio according to the instructions listed in this README.

https://github.com/zint/zint/blob/master/win32/README

However, when I get to the part where I need to do "nmake -f win32\Makefile.msc clean", I'm encountering this error: "fatal error U1052: file 'Makefile.msc' not found" despite the fact that Makefile.msc is listed out in the win32 directory.
Does anyone know why this is?

I should also note that I'm using Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022 and running it as Administrator for this task.

Comment: Are you sure you're running *NMake* from *ZLib*'s folder?